# Use DAX to create a total column based on multiple tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a number of data tables that contain an ID and relevant costs.  I want to create a column in another table that shows the total per ID.

Example main table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Rod |
| 02 | Jane |
| 03 | Freddie |

Example data table 1

| ID | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 02 | 10 |
| 02 | 15 |
| 03 | 20 |

Example data table 2

| ID | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 10 |
| 02 | 15 |
| 03 | 5 |

Desired outcome

| ID | Name | TotalCost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Rod | 10 |
| 02 | Jane | 40 |
| 03 | Freddie | 25 |

I have set up the links within Power BI between the tables so the data tables are linked to the main table by the ID, but can't get the total to work.

I'm pretty sure the solution is a SUMX, but I can't find an example of using it to link more than 2 tables (I actually have 5 data tables).

Comment: If, as you say, you have relationships between the two data tables and the main table, I don't see why you can't use a simple measure such as `=SUM(Data1[Cost])+SUM(Data2[Cost])`, which can be placed in a visual alongside the *ID* field from the main table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a calculated column to your main table, and want to take advantage of your relationships, you need to use `CALCULATE` to apply context transition.

Your calculated column DAX formula should then be:

```
TotalCost = 
CALCULATE ( 
    SUM ( 'Data1'[Cost] ) + 
    SUM ( 'Data2'[Cost] )
)
```

Alternately:

```
TotalCost = 
VAR _cost1 = 
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Data1'[Cost] ) )
VAR _cost2 = 
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Data2'[Cost] ) )
RETURN
   _cost1 + _cost2
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'd over complicated the solution.  I actually had this formula, once I deleted all the extra stuff I didn't need.

Answer (score 0):

1. calculate **measures** of cost of table 1&2:

   cost1 = sum('Table 1'[Cost])
   cost2 = sum('Table 2'[Cost])
2. in model view, you can estabilish **either single or both direction** links both works, but make sure:

- if single direction: make sure arrow of links are **from MainTable to Table1&**2:
  [image]
- both direction also works:

[image]

[image]

3. create new **column** in MainTable:

   TotalCost = [cost1]+[cost2]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer so thoroughly.  I've accepted the other answer as it quickly does what I need.  However, combining measures is something I may use in the future for another report, so wanted to acknowledge your submittal.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to avoid bidirectionality in this type of data model. Anything other than trivial measures become a royal pain to control. Besides, there is really no use for bidirectionality in this type of "simple" model anyways.

Comment: @Marcus Hi Marcus, yes i agree with you that bidirectionality may cause many calculation problems. just for this simple occasion i think bidirectionality also works. but avoid to use it is also recommended and thanks for your comments!